# Thread field inside a class that implements Runnable, which instantiates said class

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

In my school's program solutions for multithreading problems and exercises, classes that implement the `Runnable` interface are usually given a `Thread` field, which is automatically instantiated in the following example:

```java
protected Thread thr = new Thread(this);
```

This field is subsequently used as a means of controlling the Thread over which the class itself is instantiated. For example:

```java
public void stop() {
    if (thr != null) thr.interrupt();
}
```

Which is then used to interrupt `Thread` objects made with the `Runnable` class.

A full class example, ported directly from an aforementioned solution, is given below:

```java
package hokej;
import java.awt.Color;
public abstract class AktFigura extends Figura implements Runnable {
    protected Thread nit = new Thread(this);
    private int tAzur;
    private boolean radi;
    public AktFigura(Scena s, int xx, int yy,
    Color b, int t) {
        super(s, xx, yy, b); tAzur = t;
    }
    protected abstract void azurirajPolozaj();
   public void run() {
   try {
       while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
           synchronized (this) {
                if (!radi) wait();
           }
           azurirajPolozaj();
           scena.repaint();
           Thread.sleep(tAzur);
       }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
   }
   public synchronized void kreni() {
       radi = true; notify();
   }
   public void stani() { radi = false; }
   public void prekini() {
       if (nit != null) nit.interrupt();
   }
}
```

My question is this: How does this work?
Shouldn't the `Thread` field be a separate object from the object made by calling `new Thread(class);` in other parts of the program (hence the keyword's name - `new`)?
Or is this simply a special case that the Java interpreter recognizes in a certain way?

Another question would be the viability of this design as a control method. Is there any simpler/more efficient alternative for controlling a `Runnable`'s thread?

Comment: We need more code to better analyze your program.

Comment: This does not make for a good design if this is the thread that is then `start()`ed. If it is not the started Thread, then instance method calls don't make much sense.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable) Thread accepts your runnable, it doesnt matter where it asides

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I added a class example here. The rest can be found on this site http://rti.etf.bg.ac.rs/rti/ir2oo2/rokovi/OO2I170607.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does this work?

The `Thread` constructor takes a `Runnable`, `Thread` implements this interface. `this` refers to a `Thread` instance. So, the statement `Thread thr = new Thread(this)` is valid, *but this practice should be avoided.*

> Is there any simpler/more efficient alternative for controlling a Runnable's thread?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new AktFiguraImpl());
thread.start();
```

You could control a thread by a class specifically designed for that purpose.

```
class ThreadController {
    public ThreadController(Thread thread, AktFigura figura) { ... }

    // methods to manipulate the thread
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what his instructor's code is doing, albeit from within a child class -- he's calling `nit.start()` on the protected inherited field from within the Runnable itself. 1+